# Is there any relationship between number of nodes in a path/paths taken from a graph and its/their cost?

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory, probability-theory

If we take a path from a graph with X number nodes/hops , and evaluate its cost C according to its edges weights .  Can we obtain any relationship between X and C ? 
Is there anything in probability theory and graph theory that can directly or indirectly be used to infer a relationship between  these two entities? 
Suggesting  some reading resources  is very appreciated .

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask this question on the [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. There is no relation between weight of edge and length of path. Path could have length of 2 but have weight of 1000 or path of length 1000 with weight of 1 (if edges weight is real number). The weight of path can be whatever you want. I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).